# Can the NFC antenna of smart phone read signals from (active) RFID tags/transmitters

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, nfc

Can the NFC antenna of mobile phone such as the Galaxy S4 or iPhone in addition to their NFC functionality, also be used to read signals from (active) RFID tags/transmitters e.g. from 20ft away not 20cms?

Comment: No. NFC using magnetic field, for short range. RFID use electromagnetic filed, for long distance. My answer on Physics.SE http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44037/why-is-near-field-communication-nfc-range-limited-to-about-20cm/44089#44089

Comment: @ Sigrlami your answer on Physics stack exchange is brilliant!I'm new to the forum but are you able to expand on ways that this could be achieved? I assume that some sort of electromagentic device would need to intercept the active RFID tag signals and translate them to bluetooth or wifi to communicate with a smartphone?

Answer (score 2):

No. By default you can't do this, due to different principles of work and hardware chips. As I mentioned earlier my answer on [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44037/why-is-near-field-communication-nfc-range-limited-to-about-20cm/44089#44089) clarify this.

About other possibilities, there were some projects, that provide external abilities, like [Touchtag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchatag), which was on a market since 2008 to 2012. I think you can use same idea and then redirect data to audio or usb port. Then you will be need an application, to analyse incoming data.

Comment: @PatrickO' could you accept answer?